# Set tab view position from other Fragment, if tab view is hosted in Fragment instead of Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have `ActivityTwo` in my application.When `ActivityTwo` is opened I am replacing its layout with a new [fragment](/questions/tagged/fragment) which has 3 `Tabs` set using `Viewpager`.
This is code in `ActivityTwo` onCreate for calling the Fragment instantly when ActivityTwo is opened.

```
fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        String add = "";
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame, new ChooseTab(), add);
        ft.commit();
```

When button is clicked from other Fragments I am calling the same Fragment again which has my `TabView` but this time I want  to set the Tab Position to Second Tab.This is code to replace the TabView Fragment from another Fragment

```
freeTable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Confirmation.");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure to Free this Table ?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                        freeSingleTable();
                        alertMsg.successMessage(infoTable,"Table Free Successfully.");
                        ChooseTab chooseTab=new ChooseTab();
                        tx = fm.beginTransaction();
                        tx.replace(R.id.frame,chooseTab);
                        tx.commitAllowingStateLoss();

                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
```

This is code for ChooseTab Fragment which has my 3 tabs

```
public class ChooseTab extends Fragment {

    // Tab Layout and ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout;
         ViewPager viewPager;

    public ChooseTab() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_tab, container, false);
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            tabLayout=(TabLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Men"));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("women"));
            viewPager=(ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.simpleViewPager);
            viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
            PagerAdapter adapter=new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
             @Override
             public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
              viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

             }

             @Override
             public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

             }

             @Override
             public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                }
         });

            return v;
    }
}
```

How to set the TabPosition to Second Tab when the Fragment with TabView is called ?

Comment: in chooseTabl constructor you can send data or a boolean which you can decide based on how to set the position of tabs

Comment: Can you add sample code?

Comment: if you add your chooseTab code i can explain to you on that

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the tab position as an argument to ChooseTab fragment.

```
ChooseTab chooseTab=new ChooseTab();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("TAB_POSITION", yourTabPosition); 
chooseTab.setArguments(bundle);
```

In your ChooseTab fragment, use

```
tabposition = getArguments().getInt("TAB_POSITION", 0);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(tabposition);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

viewPager.setCurrentItem(x);

x = Number of tab.

Comment: in which Fragment should I add this ?

Comment: on the fragment where your button is? depends on how you want to execute your app.
if you want the second tab, use viewpager.setCurrentItem(1);
0 = first, 1 = second, so on.

Comment: But how to get that viewpager in other fragments ?

Comment: Isn't your viewPager inside ActivityTwo ? 

private ActivityTwo activityTwo;

onCreate:
activityTwo = (ActivityTwo) getActivity();

set ViewPager with: activityTwo.setViewPager(1);

Comment: the viewpager is in fargment choosetab, and choosetab fragment is on activitytwo

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your question.

Do you want just to move to the next page? if so, use `viewPager.setCurrentItem(1)` to go to the second page.

If the problem is that you want the page fragment to inform the parent fragment that it is time to change the page you can use EventBus (or another similar library) to post an event and inform the parent

-----EDIT

Ok! So the problem is that you want to communicate between the fragments. Imho, the easiest approach is to use EventBus. Alternatively, you could also create a callback like that

```
public interface OnRequestAction {

    void nextPage();

}
```

Implement this interface in the ViewPagerFragment.

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment implements OnRequestAction {

    public void nextPage() {
        int page = pager.getCurrentItem();
        pager.setCurrentItem(++page);
    }

}
```

On the tab fragment do the following

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        mCallback = (OnRequestAction) getParentFragment();
    }catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnRequestAction");
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to change page from the tab fragment just call `mCallback.nextPage();`

Comment: Yes.I want to set the tab when I call the TabView Fragment from other Fragments in my  application.